# android - how to set custom typeface in paint object?

Tags: android, paint, typeface

I want to use a `Paint` to draw something and here is my code :

```
    Paint mMonthTitlePaint = new Paint();
    mMonthTitlePaint.setFakeBoldText(true);
    mMonthTitlePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mMonthTitlePaint.setTextSize(MONTH_LABEL_TEXT_SIZE);
    mMonthTitlePaint.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/iran_sans_.ttf"));
   mMonthTitlePaint.setColor(mDayTextColor);
   mMonthTitlePaint.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);
   mMonthTitlePaint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
```

but it is not working and typeface did not apply to paint object. where is my problem? how to fix it?

here is my onDraw :

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    drawMonthNums(canvas);
}
```

and drawMonthNums :

```
protected void drawMonthNums(Canvas canvas) {
        int y = (((mRowHeight + MINI_DAY_NUMBER_TEXT_SIZE) / 2) - DAY_SEPARATOR_WIDTH)
                + getMonthHeaderSize();
        final float dayWidthHalf = (mWidth - mEdgePadding * 2) / (mNumDays * 2.0f);
        int j = findDayOffset();
        for (int dayNumber = 1; dayNumber <= mNumCells; dayNumber++) {
            final int x = (int)((2 * j + 1) * dayWidthHalf + mEdgePadding);

            int yRelativeToDay = (mRowHeight + MINI_DAY_NUMBER_TEXT_SIZE) / 2 - DAY_SEPARATOR_WIDTH;

            final int startX = (int)(x - dayWidthHalf);
            final int stopX = (int)(x + dayWidthHalf);
            final int startY = y - yRelativeToDay;
            final int stopY = startY + mRowHeight;

            drawMonthDay(canvas, mYear, mMonth, dayNumber, x, y, startX, stopX, startY, stopY);

            j++;
            if (j == mNumDays) {
                j = 0;
                y += mRowHeight;
            }
        }
    }
```

and at last this is my asset folder :

[image]

Comment: Where your font is placed?

Comment: in asset folder

Comment: I mean assets folder. Please, show a screnshot of folders in Android Studio

Comment: Could you check what returns createfromasserts function?

Comment: @Vyacheslav I debug it and typeface has been set . I want to show you its values but I dont know how

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
    Typeface tf =Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/iran_sans_.ttf");
   Paint paint = new Paint();
   paint.setTypeface(tf);
   canvas.drawText("Sample text",0,0,paint);
```

you can also use the `Textpaint` class instead of `Paint`

```
   TextPaint textPaint = new TextPaint();
    textPaint.setTextSize(20);
    textPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);
    textPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    Typeface tf =Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/iran_sans_.ttf");
    textPaint.setTypeface(tf);
```

see this: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextPaint.html

Comment: you can draw text using the paint object.

Comment: it is a big class and canvas is very later set. can I set one not important canvas ? just for applying typeface

Comment: @faezesaghafi At where your canvas is drawing ? Have you applied it in _onDraw()_ method

Comment: @Piyush : yes drawMonthNums(canvas); in this method

Comment: see this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13288182/custom-font-not-working-on-android

Comment: try changing some other font...also where is your `canvas.drawText` method

Comment: @rafsanahmad007 find canvas.drawText and problem solved... THANK YOU <3